# Is it possible to enforce DbContext.MyTable.Local members to have auto ID assigned before DbContext.SaveChanges() execution? (EFCore + SQLite)

Tags: .net, sqlite, orm, entity-framework-core, rdbms

So I was trying to access my local *(or you may call it "temporary/runtime/RAM")* database *(using SQLite with EF Core)* before actually saving it on hard-drive. Found out that I can access to local `myTable` with `DbContext.MyTable.Local` but the problem is the auto-increment for `ID` was not assigned yet. So can I enforce my local table members to have auto-assigned `ID` before executing `DbContext.SaveChanges()`? If not, what is the alternative?

Here's my codes:

```
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    private static MyDbContext _myDbContext = new MyDbContext();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass newClass = new MyClass() { Name = "MyName", Amount = 10 };
        _myDbContext.MyClasses.ToList();    // forcing to have all members in "_myDbContext.MyClasses.Local". Otherwise only changed/added etc. members appear.
        _myDbContext.MyClasses.Add(newClass);

        int myNewID = newClass.ID; 
        // I need newClass.ID that has been auto-assigned here, but it's currently integer default so myNewID value is 0

        _myDbContext.SaveChanges();
        int myNewerId = newClass.ID;
        // now have new auto-assigned newClass.ID value but It's too late
    }
}
```

My model:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }

    private static bool _created = false;
    public MyDbContext()
    {
        if (!_created)
        {
            _created = true;
            //Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
    {
        optionbuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=..\TestDB.db");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, and why it's "too late" to get the ID after the record has been saved?

Comment: I was trying to let user to manipulate his local database and save the changes to actual database only via "Save to Database" button.

Comment: It's too late because I'm putting values (including ID) on local database before saving on actual database

Comment: I'm not sure about your particular use-case, but you should be able to create an interface where the user can manipulate a list of objects, and then save it to the DB when they're done. I'm not sure why you need the ID to be assigned prior to saving it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

In EF, if a model has an `ID` property as an int, it should automatically set it to PK and auto-increment, unless you specify otherwise. If the question is simply "can I obtain an auto-generated ID without saving to the DB," the answer is no, you cannot.

In order to get the ID for an auto-generated ID column, you must save the changes to the database first. After that, the new record's `ID` property will be set.

```
MyClass newClass = new MyClass() { 
  Name = "MyName", 
  Amount = 10 
};
_myDbContext.MyClasses.Add(newClass);
_myDbContext.SaveChanges();

//newClass.ID will be set here.
```

If you're using an auto-generated column, this is just the only way to do it. If you want to set the ID yourself - like using a uuid - you could make that change to the ID column. In the case of a uuid that would involve changing the type of the ID column to string, and you'll want to set a `MaxLength` to whatever the length of the thing you choose to use.

```
class MyClass
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can manually assign the ID before the DB changes have been written.

Also, in this line

```
_myDbContext.MyClasses.ToList();    // forcing to have all members in "_myDbContext.MyClasses.Local". Otherwise only changed/added etc. members appear.
```

I'm not sure I understand your logic here, but there's no reason to do this just to save a new record to the database, and doing so will drastically slow down your application as your database grows. As it stands, you're requesting a list of every item in the table, but you're not even saving it to a variable, so this line is doing nothing more than to slow down your program.

Comment: so, I need to to save database to get ID value... I was trying to let user to manipulate his local database and save the changes to actual database via "Save to Database" button.

on the last code-line you mentioned: If I don't put that line then my "MyTable.Local" members are only the members I added/changed, the other unchanged members was not shown. On debug mod VS2019 said: "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" so I believe reading all members via calling .ToList() method somehow sign all members to "changed" (or something like that) so I can see all members